# Probability with powers of $2$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

There are $2^H$ tickets. Let $k<H$ (and so $2^k$ is a submultiple of $2^H$).

Let $D$ be a random integer number taken uniformly from $1,2,..k$. Then $2^D$ is in turn a submultiple of $2^k$ and then also of  $2^H$.

Once we select $D$ at random, we pick at random one ticket every $2^D$ tickets. That is, we divide the $2^H$ tickets in $\frac{2^H}{2^D}$ distinct groups and we pick at random one ticket from each group (indeed we will then pick $\frac{2^H}{2^D}$ tickets).

What is in the end the probability of being picked for each ticket in the set of $2^H$ tickets?

Comment: What do you mean we pick at random one ticket every $2^D$ tickets?

Comment: I updated the post.. now it should be more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $D=1$, which has probability $\frac 1k$, the chance a ticket is picked is $\frac 12$.  If $D=2$, also probability $\frac 1k$, the chance a ticket is picked is $\frac 1{2^2}$  The total probability a ticket is picked is then $$\frac 1k\sum_{i=1}^k \frac 1{2^i}=\frac 1k\left(1-\frac 1{2^k}\right)$$

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I am trying to understand your solution and I am near to elect it as the answer.. can you explain why the summation goes from 1 to k?

Comment: @Johan Because those are the possible values of $D$.

Comment: Because the allowable range of $D$ is from $1$ to $k$.  Each term in the sum corresponds to one value of $D$

Comment: This is the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Take a ticket $a$. This ticket is grouped together with other tickets, forming a group of $2^D$ tickets. One of those will be chosen, resulting in $P=\frac{1}{2^D}=2^{-D}$.

Comment: $D$ is chosen as part of the random process, so the final probability can't depend on it (it should depend only on $H$ and $k$).